# Using a conditional inside of a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, html

I'm using a php foreach statement like this:

```
<?php foreach($files as $f): ?>
```

lots of HTML

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

how can I put a conditional inside the loop that so that it will skip ahead to the next iteration. I know that I'm supposed to use continue, but I'm not sure how to do it with closed php statements like this. Would it be a separate php statement? Could it be placed halfway down in the HTML so that some but not all of the stuff within the loop is executed?

Comment: Well, in between. Where you need it.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? and some code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can insert the condition and `continue` wherever you want:

```
<?php foreach($files as $f): ?>

lots of HTML

<?php if (condition) continue; ?>

more HTML

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/WbiWH).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and all searches led me here. Hope somebody finds my post useful. From my own code:
For PHP 5.3.0 this worked:

```
foreach ($aMainArr as $aCurrentEntry) {
    $nextElm = current($aMainArr); //the 'current' element is already one element ahead of the already fetched but this happens just one time!
    if ($nextElm) {
        $nextRef = $nextElm['the_appropriate_key'];
        next($aMainArr); //then you MUST continue using next, otherwise you stick!
    } else { //caters for the last element
    further code here...
    }
//further code here which processes $aMainArr one entry at a time...
}
```

For PHP 7.0.19 the following worked:

```
reset($aMainArr);
foreach ($aMainArr as $aCurrentEntry) {
    $nextElm = next($aMainArr);
    if ($nextElm) {
        $nextRef = $nextElm['the_appropriate_key'];
    } else { //caters for the last element
    further code here...
    }
//further code here which processes $aMainArr one entry at a time...
}
```